# jQuery: $.get(url) breaks my sequential script execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, get

My attention is to check a calculated Image URI, if it exists…

If i do this for images, that are shown as overlays:

```
$.get(first_url).done(function(){
  $('#any_DOM_id').append('<img id="first_image" src="'+first_url+'"/>');
}).fail(function(){
  $('#any_DOM_id').append('<img id="first_image" src="'+fallback_url+'"/>');
});

/*** HERE is something big happening and is calculated ***/
.
. 
.
. 
.
$.get(second_url).done(function(){
  $('#any_DOM_id').append('<img id="second_image" src="'+second_url+'"/>');
}).fail(function(){
  $('#any_DOM_id').append('<img id="second_image" src="'+fallback_url+'"/>');
});
.
. 
.
$.get(third_url).done(function(){
  $('#any_DOM_id').append('<img id="third_image" src="'+third_url+'"/>');
}).fail(function(){
  $('#any_DOM_id').append('<img id="third_image" src="'+fallback_url+'"/>');
});
.
. 
.
$('#any_DOM_id').append('<img id="fourth_image" src="'+fourth_url+'"/>');
```

my sequential Chronology is broken, so the images are not in the right position at the layers.
Have I to use $.get on all images, or does $.get kills the Chronology always?

**EDIT:**

This is what i'am doing:
[image]

the images have to be in order like this:

```
<style>
  .image_wrapper{
    position:relative;
  }
  .image_wrapper img{
    position:absolute;
  }     
</style>
<div id="image_wrapper">
  <img id="first_image" src="first_url"/>
  <img id="second_image" src="second_url"/>
  <img id="third_image" src="third_url"/>
  <img id="fourth_image" src="fourth_url"/>
</div>
```

Comment: `$.get()` is asynchronous

Comment: is there a synchronous pendant for it?

Comment: may with $.ajax async: false ?? right?

Comment: @Viktor As @Karl-AndréGagnon noticed, using `$.ajax` with `async: false` is deprecated since jQuery 1.8.

Comment: As you add many images with the same id, it's not clear what you really want.

Comment: that was a mistake. Maybe the image is showing what i am doing a bit clearer

Answer (score 2):

You can use the always callback :

```
$.get(first_url).done(function(){
    $('#any_DOM_id').append('<img id="my_image" src="'+first_url+'"/>');
}).fail(function(){
    $('#any_DOM_id').append('<img id="my_image" src="'+fallback_url+'"/>');
}).always(function(){
    $('#any_DOM_id').append('<img id="my_image" src="'+second_url+'"/>');
    $('#any_DOM_id').append('<img id="my_image" src="'+third_url+'"/>');
    $('#any_DOM_id').append('<img id="my_image" src="'+fourth_url+'"/>');
});
```

> Add handlers to be called when the Deferred object is either resolved or rejected.

[jQuery .always()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/)

---

## Edit

You can create a function with a callback. The callback receive the url (fallback or good one) That function receive an array of URL and do the requests in order :

```
checkURI([first_url, second_url, third_url, fourth_url], function(src){
    $('#any_DOM_id').append('<img id="my_image" src="'+src+'"/>');
})

function checkURI(uri, callback){
    get(0)
    function get(i){
        if(typeof uri[i] !== 'undefined')
            $.get(uri[i])
            .done(function(){
                callback(uri);
                get(i++);
            }).fail(function(){
                callback('YOUR FALLBACK URL');
                get(i++);
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: the last three images are loaded many times later, so i can't do this like that

Comment: @Viktor See my edit, i've created a function that you can reuse.

Comment: Are you sure that's not a `!== 'undefined`` ? Also, @Viktor the solution is to use a real promise library like Bluebird that will gladly eat this sort of problem for breakfast rather than using jQuery's extremely bad promises.

Answer (score 2):

Using `.reduce()` like a boss

```
[first_url, second_url, third_url, fourth_url].reduce(function(promise, url) {
    return promise.then(function() {
        return $.get(url);
    }).then(function(urlContents) {
        $('#any_DOM_id').append('<img id="my_image" src="'+url+'"/>');
    }).then(null, function() {
        $('#any_DOM_id').append('<img id="my_image" src="'+fallback_url+'"/>');
        return $().promise();
    });
}, $().promise());
```

Comment: Duplicate IDs, but +1 for reducing like a boss.

Comment: But then the requests are sequential

Comment: @dystroy concurrent requests is even simpler but the OP wanted sequential?

Comment: I think he rather wanted to put the right things at the right place. But I'm not 100% sure. EDIT : I've read the question many times... I don't get it, especially the part where many images with same ID are added :\

Comment: `$.when.apply([url1,url2,url3,url4].map($.get).map(function(p){ p = p.then(null,function(e,i){ return $.get(fallback_urls[i]);}).then(function(a1,a2,a3,a4){ /* append all`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum .map calls $.get like (url, index, length) :P

Answer (score 0):

or maybe as a check_function inside an if?!?

```
if(check_uri($uri)){
  $('#any_DOM_id').append('<img id="my_image" src="'+first_url+'"/>');
}else{
  $('#any_DOM_id').append('<img id="my_image" src="'+fallback_url+'"/>');
}

var check_uri = function($uri){
  $.get($uri).done(function(){
    return true;
  }).fail(function(){
    return false;   
  });
};
```

Comment: no, still asynchronous. if is not waiting for get back a value.